# Overcoming MS DTC Limitations when using Mirroring

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, wcf-data-services, msdtc, database-mirroring

An unforeseen requirement has hit our team. Our SQL Servers, 2008 R2, are using a mirroring setup on two databases. We supplied a WCF Data Service for clients to consume including the web development team.

The other team found that they had so many reports that given our time frame a port is not feasible. We had only one real option which was to *update* (note not create or delete) the legacy system single table, running on Sql Server 2000. By doing that we ensured that all the report would be still usable.

The web developer team found that MS DTC kept throwing exceptions. I pointed out that Cross-Database MS DTC cannot be used with sql servers using mirroring. What sprange to mind was a Unit Of Work pattern. We could then use individual transactions in the SQL Servers, in this case 3 operations must all complete successfully in order to complete the Unit Of Work.

Is this a good way to overcome this technology limitation? Are their any other factors to consider?

Comment: I don't think a unit of work fits while maintaining strict ACID transaction properties.  You could think about compensating transactions but those are fraught with peril (not guaranteed of consistent state).

Comment: Do you have any sources for the perilous route? Any other considerations to take into account?